# RN Facebook auth with Firebase - No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Facebook authentication on firebase based react-native app (IOS).

- configured my app in facebook developer dashboard.
- configured facebook auth details in firebase dashboard and enabled the authentication.
- added necessary lines to my plist.info file

as far as I can see,

1. I am getting a token from facebook
2. I see successful authentication in facebook console, and getting an alert in my faceook account

**but the function "signInWithCredential" is failing with the error:**

```
Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()
```

I am initializing firebase configuration before this function is being called.. so I am not sure what the real issue is :o

any other firebase query/call is working fine.

my facebook authentication function (found online):

```
const facebookLogin = async() => {
    // Attempt login with permissions
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);

    if (result.isCancelled) {
        throw 'User cancelled the login process';
    }

    // Once signed in, get the users AccesToken
    const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    if (!data) {
        throw 'Something went wrong obtaining access token';
    }

    // Create a Firebase credential with the AccessToken
    const facebookCredential = auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential); ** --> FAILS HERE **
};
```

I'll be glad for any help guys..
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out,
needed to import my firebase object after connection, and use it to call the 'auth' actions:

```
    // Create a Firebase credential with the AccessToken
const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);

// Sign-in the user with the credential
return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
```